# Django use ORM to get range of a particular element

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have a model called MyModel which has some dummy data as follows:

```
     item    date     value
------------------------------
      ab    8/10/12     1
      ab    7/10/12     2
      ab    6/10/12     3
      abc   8/10/12     4
      abc   7/10/12     5
      abc   7/10/12     6
      ab    7/10/12     7
      ab    7/10/12     8
      ab    7/10/12     9
      ab    7/10/12     10
      abc   7/10/12     11
      abc   7/10/12     12
      abc   7/10/12     13
```

I would like to query this Model in such a way that i get an output the gives me the ranges of the items that are in serial, something like the following:

```
[{'item': 'ab', 'values': '1-3'},
 {'item': 'abc', 'values': '4-6'},
 {'item': 'ab', 'values': '7-10'},
 {'item': 'abc', 'values': '11-13'}]
```

How would i be able to do this using the django ORM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty certain you can't do that with the ORM...you'll need to write your own python code to do that.

```
counts = []

for model in MyModel.objects.all().order_by('value'):
  if not counts or last_item != model.item:
    counts.append({'item': model.item, 'values': [ model.value ]})
    last_item = model.item
  elsif model.item == last_item:
    counts[-1]['values'].append(model.value)

for count in counts:
  count['values'] = '%s-%s' % (count['values'][0], count['values'][-1])
```

Edit:

```
counts = []

for model in MyModel.objects.all().order_by('value'):
  if not counts or last_item != model.item:
    counts.append({'item': model.item, 'first': model.value, 'last':model.value})
    last_item = model.item
  elsif model.item == last_item:
    counts[-1][last] = model.value
```

Comment: hi simple question.. What should i change in the code to get the values as "begin" and "end"? Like i want {"begin":1, "end":3} instead of the values list.